# Trying to map an array of objects in react

Tags: reactjs, data-structures, mern

im doing a mern app, and i need to map over an array of objects, but the problem is that, the way i structure the data didn't put me in a good position to do it...

Here's the thing

this is my data

[image]

Inside task, there is an object, and inside that object we got more stuff...

[image]

I need to get to this data and show it in my website

[image]

So far, i only got to the creator

```
  const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks.map(room => room.creator));

  console.log(tasks);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide data as text, not as pictures of text.

Answer (score 2):

The role of selectors is to select data from the state manager (redux in that context).

So firstly, fix your selector and select the tasks:

```
const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks);
```

Secondly,
Iterate over the tasks array and output the data you want:

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
 const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks);
 return (
  <ul>
   {
    tasks.map((task, index) => {
     <li key={index}>{task.task}</li>
   }
  }
 </ul>
 );
}
```

Comment: Unique `key` on `<li>` perhaps?

Comment: Added key to <il> by tasks array item index.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question!

but your solution didn't work for me :/, it gave a huge error, and the problem is that, what i'm receving from the redux, it's an array with objects, and i can only access them if i ask for the index, and if i try to map it, console would say tasks.map is not a function, so i'm going to try to change the structure of my data, and again, thank you homie !

Comment: But, do you know how can i get to the array of name task to iterate over it ?